# Java FXML TextArea.setText() Stops Working

Tags: java, fxml

I am trying to update a TextArea in my Java FXML program and am encountering a weird problem. I am able to update the instructions 2 times but on the third instance of the same update call the text field will not update. I am using the same method call for all updates and have gotten what should be displayed to print in the console, so I know the problem is with the TextArea update. Here is the code causing the problem:

```
private void freedomCheck(){        // method for starting out a composition, choosing "mode"
    decisionIndex = 0;
    this.addChord("I");                 //initialize first chord to "I"
    prompt[0] = "Please enter your degree of freedom: 1, 2, 3, or 4."; //display prompt
    prompt[1] = "1: Composes and plays for you";
    prompt[2] = "2: Fill in just notes with chords given to you";
    prompt[3] = "3: Fill in chords and notes, with software giving you options for both";
    prompt[4] = "4: Fill in chords and notes with full independence";
    prompt();                   // get user input (can be changed to button press, etc.

}

private void prompt(){
    String displayString = "";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        displayString += prompt[i] + "\n";
    }
    setInstructions(displayString);
    System.out.println(displayString);
}

    public void setInstructions(String newString){
    instruction_text.setText(newString);
}
```

The prompt[] array is used to quickly separate lines of text. This section of the code works and prints correctly on the display, but later when I try to update it with the same prompt() call:

```
    public void promptNotes(){
    decisionIndex = 4;
    int index;
    if (composition.noteLength() == 0)
        index = composition.getSize() - 1;
    else index = composition.noteLength();
    prompt[0] = "The current chord is " + composition.getChord(index).getName() + "; please pick a note:";//prompt

    Chord temp = composition.getChord(composition.getSize()-1);
    ArrayList<Note> candidates = temp.getOfferedNotes();
    int notesLen = candidates.size();       //length of notes list for current chord

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++){
        tempNotes[i] = candidates.get(notesLen - i);
        prompt[i] = (i+1) + ": " + tempNotes[i].getName();
    }
    prompt();
}
```

The correct output is printed to the console, but the textArea does not update.

Comment: Verify that you are in fact updating the same TextArea each time, by adding this to the setInstructions method:  `System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(instruction_text));`  If a different value is printed each time, you are not updating the same TextArea that’s on the screen.

Comment: Tried adding it, same code appeared on the initial setting of the text and on the only working update. It also appeared on the non-working update, same number. Output was: 

2133816938
Please enter your degree of freedom: 1, 2, 3, or 4.
1: Composes and plays for you
2: Fill in just notes with chords given to you
3: Fill in chords and notes, with software giving you options for both
4: Fill in chords and notes with full independence

2133816938
2133816938
The current chord is I; please pick a note:
2: C7
3: E7
4: G7
5: C8

2133816938

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Also to clarify, the "1:...4:..." part did update to the textArea, but the "The current chord is..." didn't update. There was a successful update between them that triggered the second number but was not set to output its text to the console.